# CefSharp javascript element click doesn't work, but clicking on it manually does

Tags: javascript, jquery, chromium-embedded, cefsharp, siebel

I am trying to automatically maneuver through a web page.  I get to a page with a table and I am trying to go to the next page.  The element for going to the next page looks like so:

```
<td id="last_pager_s_1_l" class="ui-pg-button ui-corner-all" style="cursor: default;"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-seek-end" title="Next record set"></span></td>
```

I try to click on this programmatically using:

```
JavascriptResponse response = await browser.EvaluateScriptAsync("document.getElementById('last_pager_s_1_l').click()");
```

response.success = true so it looks like it clicks, but nothing happens on the page.  When I use the mouse to click on it, it advances the page and the console shows the following:

```
CONSOLE: GotoNextSet (https://<url>/23030/scripts/siebel/siebjs.js?_scb=|38)
```

Obviously the function needed to go to the next page is located in the siebjs.js file which is loaded in the page as follows:

```
<script language="javascript" src="23030/scripts/siebel/siebjs.js?_scb="></script>
```

Does anyone know how to invoke the function within siebjs.js file that would advance the page?

Thanks,
Jim

Comment: If you execute your script in `DecTools` console what happens?

Comment: It does nothing and returns undefined.  Just as a test I executed a click on another element and it worked correctly and also returned undefined.  I looked and there is a listener for the click event.  I unchecked Ancestors and Framework listeners and there was still one there.  It links to 

jquery.js?_scb=:2746

Comment: I actually tried running that line and I get:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateOn (<anonymous>:875:140)
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap (<anonymous>:808:34)
    at Object.InjectedScript.evaluate (<anonymous>:664:21)InjectedScript._evaluateOn @ VM347:875InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap @ VM347:808InjectedScript.evaluate @ VM347:664

It just seems like a programmatic click should be the same as a physical one.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you want to want to automate user behaviour in Siebel, and if you are using a Siebel running Open UI, then the [WebDriver approach](https://www.google.nl/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=webdriver+for+C%23) might help you to do what you want to do.

On the Selenium Project page a specific download for [C# libraries](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#c) can be found.

Comment: You are correct in that I wanted to automate user behavior in Siebel.  I found this link:  http://www.siebelhub.com/main/2015/03/displaying-the-number-of-child-records-in-siebel-crm.html  and this gave me some insight on how to query Siebel directly using injected java script.  The solution was rather long and there didn't seem to be much interest in this post so I never posted how I did it.